# Actualizar datos en dataGridView al mostrar

Tags: c#, sql-server, datagridview

Buenas tengo un campo en una base de datos SQLServer el cual contiene una columna llamada Flag que contiene 0 o 1. Necesito que cuando muestro los datos en el dataGridView me sustituya en la vista los 0 por una N y los 1 por V. ¿Qué metodo puedo utilizar? Asi es como muestro los datos:

```
            string fechaDesde = dateDatosMensualesDesde.Value.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss.fff");
            string fechaHasta = dateDatosMensualesHasta.Value.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss.fff");


            string query = "SELECT * FROM mensual WHERE Fecha BETWEEN '" + fechaDesde + "' AND '" + fechaHasta + "' ";
            SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(conexion);
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(query, cn);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            //aqui necesitaría un método que me cambie los 0 por N y los 1 por V solo para mostrarlos
            da.Fill(ds);
            dataGridMensuales.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
```

Gracias.

Comment: Deberias agregar una propiedad a tu modelo, y en el get , hacer la pregunta y retornar el valor que quieres.

Comment: En tu query puedes agregar  algo como  
      CASE Flag
         WHEN 0 THEN 'N'  
         ELSE 'V'  
      END